# Create Rally user story and map features using Rest API

Tags: rally, code-rally

How to create  user story and map existing features id. below are my code snippet.
J

```
sonObject newEpic = new JsonObject();
        newEpic.addProperty("Name", "Test User story");
        newEpic.addProperty("Workspace", "/workspace/59461540346");
        newEpic.addProperty("Project", "/project/1575156879");      
        newEpic.addProperty("Owner", UserInfo("xxxxx", rallyRestApi));
        newEpic.addProperty("Feature", "/feature/29047088908");
        CreateRequest createRequest1 = new CreateRequest("hierarchicalrequirement", newEpic);
        CreateResponse createResponse1 = rallyRestApi.create(createRequest1);
```

The above code, created user story in rally but not mapped with features. 
How can i do that? any idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps change this line:

```
newEpic.addProperty("Feature", "/feature/29047088908");
```

To this:

```
newEpic.addProperty("PortfolioItem", "/feature/29047088908");
```